# How to restore and execute two independent TensorFlow models?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm developing a program based on TensorFlow and two different models are required. According to the output of the first model, I perform some calcs and I have the input for the second one. Here part of the code:

```
key_pose_model = None
gesture_model = None


# Key Poses
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    if key_pose_model_type == 'ramdon_forest':
        key_pose_model = RandomForest(key_pose_ramdon_forest_num_steps,
                                key_pose_ramdon_forest_num_classes,
                                key_pose_ramdon_forest_num_trees,
                                key_pose_ramdon_forest_max_nodes,
                                key_pose_ramdon_forest_num_features)
        key_pose_model.read_model(key_pose_model_name)


# Gestures
with tf.device('/cpu:1'):
    if gesture_model_type == 'ramdon_forest':
        gesture_model = RandomForest(gesture_ramdon_forest_num_steps,
                                gesture_ramdon_forest_num_classes,
                                gesture_ramdon_forest_num_trees,
                                gesture_ramdon_forest_max_nodes,
                                gesture_ramdon_forest_num_features)
        gesture_model.read_model(gesture_model_name)
```

Latter I have the following calls in my code (input data is obtained from sensors):

```
while(True):
......
......
key_pose_model.prediction(input_data_x)
......
......
......
......
gesture_model.prediction(input_data_x_1)
.......
```

It works well for the first model, then when I restore the second one, I have the error of duplicate variables, so I think I'm not using another graph. I was reading the TensorFlow documentation and I tried to reproduce the example about different sessions but I couldn't.

```
g_1 = tf.Graph()
with g_1.as_default():
  # Operations created in this scope will be added to `g_1`.
  c = tf.constant("Node in g_1")

  # Sessions created in this scope will run operations from `g_1`.
  sess_1 = tf.Session()

g_2 = tf.Graph()
with g_2.as_default():
  # Operations created in this scope will be added to `g_2`.
  d = tf.constant("Node in g_2")

# Alternatively, you can pass a graph when constructing a <a href="./../api_docs/python/tf/Session"><code>tf.Session</code></a>:
# `sess_2` will run operations from `g_2`.
sess_2 = tf.Session(graph=g_2)

assert c.graph is g_1
assert sess_1.graph is g_1

assert d.graph is g_2
assert sess_2.graph is g_2
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of the typo in `'ramdon_forest'`?

Comment: Ohhh I didn't notice the typo, well but it's just a variable name.